# Как правильно вывести разные значение массива в разные блоки?

Tags: php, массивы

Есть такой массив

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
        [value1] => Текст 1
        [value2] => Текст 2
        [value3] => Текст 3
        [value4] => 
    ) 
    [1] => Array ( 
        [value1] => Текст 1
        [value2] => Текст 2
        [value3] => 
        [value4] =>
    )
    [2] => Array ( 
        [value1] =>
        [value2] =>
        [value3] => 
        [value4] => СУПЕР ТЕКСТ
    )
)
```

Как правильно вывести значения массива раскидав их по разным блокам?
К примеру, если есть значения value1 и value2, то в один блок, если ТОЛЬКО value4 то в другой блок.

```
<div id='BLOCK1'>
 <span>Текст 1 Текст 2 Текст 3</span>
 <span>Текст 1 Текст 2</span>
</div>
<div id='BLOCK2'>
 <span>СУПЕР ТЕКСТ</span>
</div>
```

Comment: как как. проверять условия и выводить. желательно только сначала подготовить данные, а потом уже выводить.

Comment: Хорошо, а как мне скрыть блок если к примеру в <div id='BLOCK2'> не будет данных.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Прежде чем что-либо выводить, подготовьте данные в удобной форме, например, следующим образом, используя фильтрацию по блокам.

Исходные данные

```
$data = [
    [
        'value1' => "Текст 1",
        'value2' => "Текст 2",
        'value3' => "Текст 3",
        'value4' => null,
    ], 
    [
        'value1' => "Текст 1",
        'value2' => "Текст 2",
        'value3' => null,
        'value4' => null,
    ],
    [
        'value1' => null,
        'value2' => null,
        'value3' => null,
        'value4' => "СУПЕР ТЕКСТ",
    ]
];
```

Далее следует определить функции фильтрации для каждого блока, и применить их

```
$blocks = [
        'block1' => function($v){ return !(empty($v['value1']) || empty($v['value2'])); },
        'block4' => function($v){ return $v['value4'] && empty($v['value1']) && empty($v['value2']); }
    ];

$result = [];
foreach($blocks as $block => &$filter){
    $result[$block] = array_filter($data, $filter);
}

print_r($result);
```

а далее уже выводить отфильтрованные данные.

как пример вывода можно привести следующий код, хотя я и не сторонник генерации html-кода в пхп без использования шаблонизаторов.

```
foreach($result as $block => $items){
    if(!count($items)) continue;

    echo "<div id='{$block}'>\n";
    foreach($items as $item){
        echo "  <span>".implode(' ', array_filter($item))."</span>\n";
    }
    echo "</div>\n";
}
```

результатом работы данного кода будет

```
<div id='block1'>
  <span>Текст 1 Текст 2 Текст 3</span>
  <span>Текст 1 Текст 2</span>
</div>
<div id='block4'>
  <span>СУПЕР ТЕКСТ</span>
</div>
```

Альтернативой будет, конечно, обычный вывод данных. Вам потребуется сделать цикл для каждого блока, где и проверять условия.

Comment: Спасибо, фильт это, что мне нужно было.